# deepcopy after np.delete. Bug?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, deep-copy

I have an object with an attribute that is an 2D array of lists.
Sometimes I delete columns from the array.
Sometimes I want to use deepcopy on the object.

However, this gave me a bug, as illustrated by the examples below.

```
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy
```

Create array of lists

```
A = np.empty((2,3),list)
for i,j in np.ndindex(A.shape):
    A[i,j] = [i,j]
```

Delete, copy. Two versions that fail

```
B = np.delete(A,[0],1)
C = deepcopy(B)
print("These two should be the same")
print(B[0,1])
print(C[0,1])

B = np.array(np.delete(A,[0],1))
C = deepcopy(B)
print("These two should be the same")
print(B[0,1])
print(C[0,1])
```

The output is

```
These two should be the same
[0, 2]
[1, 1]
These two should be the same
[0, 2]
[1, 1]
```

The following versions work as expected

```
B = np.delete(A,[0],1)
C = np.empty_like(B); C[:] = B
print("These two should be the same")
print(B[0,1])
print(C[0,1])

B = np.delete(A,0,1)
C = deepcopy(B)
print("These two should be the same")
print(B[0,1])
print(C[0,1])

B = np.delete(A,0,1)
C = B.copy()
print("These two should be the same")
print(B[0,1])
print(C[0,1])

B = np.ascontiguousarray(np.delete(A,[0],1))
C = deepcopy(B)
print("These two should be the same")
print(B[0,1])
print(C[0,1])
```

The output is

```
These two should be the same
[0, 2]
[0, 2]
... etc
```

Some insight can be gained by looking at the flags of the arrays. But in any case, the behaviour is unexpected. Note also how very similar some working versions are failing version. Is it a numpy bug?

Comment: I copied your "failing" code and got [0, 2] consistently. My version of NumPy is 1.13.1, Python 3.6.1.

Comment: @Desire The question used NumPy 1.11.1. Now I tested with 1.13.1 and can confirm your finding: the problem is gone. Guess it was a bug...